# Make element Middle when using float

Tags: css

I try to make 2 columns using float. left column has short text and another is long text [like](http://jsfiddle.net/4My36/)

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box1">short text</div>
    <div class="box2">This is a long text This is a long text This is a long text <br> This is a long text <br> This is a long text <br></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
.box1 {
    float:left;
}
.box2 {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Before is

[image]

And I try make it become

[image]

But i can't make box1 is middle when box2 has dynamic long text. Is that possible? How to do that. Thanks.

Comment: You mean like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/5xKM2/3/

Comment: You need to be more explicit as to what you are trying to do? Do you want to center the two boxes?

Comment: I try to make box1 `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle` but it can't work

Comment: why dont you use tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this suits you, you can do it with `display:inline-block`

change your css to:

```
.box1 {
    //float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.box2 {
    //float:left;
    width: 50%;
     display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

see here:http://jsfiddle.net/Jr9Fp/

or you can use a `display:table` on the parent and `display:table-cell` on the children like this:

```
.boxes{
    display:table;
    background:#ccc;
}

.box1 {
    //float:left;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:red;
    height:100%;
}
.box2 {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    display:table-cell;
   // vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jr9Fp/1/

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
.box1{
   width: 200px;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;

}
.box2{
   width: 400px;
   float: right;
}
```

demo. http://jsfiddle.net/doniyor/44nE2/